# Cannot display inline chart in IPython notebook

Tags: matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I've seen the exact same question around but the answers didn't help me. like those questions:
[Cannot show the graphs on ipython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27751261/cannot-show-the-graphs-on-ipython-notebook)

[How to make IPython notebook matplotlib plot inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410042/how-to-make-ipython-notebook-matplotlib-plot-inline)

So I decided to post a question so i could post my code, see if there is anything different... hopefully it's something very dull that I'm missing. although the code runs perfectly in ipython shell.  Thanks in advance !

```
%matplotlib inline

import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 3*np.pi, 500)
plt.plot(x, np.sin(x**2))
plt.title('A simple chirp')
plt.show()
```

PS: I'm using Anaconda distribution, and I launched notebook by the shortcut that comes with it `IPython (Python 2.7) Notebook`

PS2: the output I get is virtually none.

[image]

Comment: this works fine for me in a notebook.

Comment: That's weird. I'll try to post a screenshot. Maybe something to do with the distribution ?

Comment: [here's a screenshot from me](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wvf9nfpqpdfkgu2/Screenshot%202015-08-14%2014.44.55.png)

Comment: oh all right. that's just odd ! maybe some issue with firefox ? windows 7 ? you just clicked Cell > Run All or Shift+ Enter or whatever right ?

Comment: I clicked the play button, but just tried Cell>Run All and Shift+Enter, and both worked

Comment: god that's frustrating. but thank you a lot for tyring to help. I'll just reboot the whole thing !

Comment: Do I have to save the notebook to any specific directory ? basic code like (1+3) works

Comment: no, it should just work wherever you are.

Comment: That little * in the In[] box means you're supposed to wait.  Maybe something is confusing your program.  Does it ever go away?

Comment: out of the blue it works ! thanks a lots guys ! I think I'll delete this question though, doesn't really add anything to anyone, since it ghostly fixed itself. thanks !